# Outlook 2007 Add-In Does Not Load on Outlook 2013

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, add-in

We have built a VTSO office add-in using Visual Studio 2008 (C#,vsto 2.0 runtime) targeting office 2007 as the minimum version. Works fine on 2007 and 2010 version of outlook, word, excel and power point. 
It is also working on 2013 version of word, excel and power point but do not load on outlook 2013. We do not get any kind of error message. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Vikas

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it not showing any error when you set the environment variable
   "VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS" with value "0"?
2. Did you also checked if it is in disabled items list in File =>
   Options => Add-Ins => Manage choose disabled items?

Comment: Hi Kiru, thanks for help but we already tried with setting "VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS" variable but it is not displaying any error, also it is not listed in disabled item either.

Comment: @user2645536 Did you tried to manually load the addins from Developer tab in the ribbon? Also check the loadbehaviour in the registry entry, it should be 3 by default

Comment: The addin is not visible in the addins list to load manually, also the registry entry is there for word, excel and power point but not for outlook

Comment: which means the addin is not installed properly please reinstall again

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have reinstalled it again but same result, do you think if I upgrade my solution to VS2010 or VS2012 it will help? but then will it continue to support outlook 2007 and 2010. I need to support all of these three versions(i.e office 2007, 2010 and 2010).

Comment: There is no harm in upgrading to VS2012, but I am not sure if that solves your problem. You might have to look in to why it is not able to create registry entries just like other addins. I might need more details like how your installation/deployment of addins work to go further.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2013 doesn't support add-ins that target 2007. It supports 2010 add-ins only.